# What are good ways to counter jungle an AP Shaco?

Tags: league-of-legends

I like to jungle and am never able to counter jungle AP Shacos due to their boxes. Anybody have some good suggestions? I normally jungle Fiddlesticks.

Comment: could always harass him, i find fiddlesticks to usually have an advantage over most champions in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Invade.  If you stop Shaco early by ruining his boxes, killing him at level 1, or taking his buffs he will not be able to gank as succesfully.  He will also not be able to counter jungle you and he will be behind the whole game unless he gets a couple kills from people playing overly aggressive without wards.  A level two/three shaco gank without red unless that lane has hard cc has a lot lower chance of success then a shaco with a red buff.

Answer (score 0):

Many shacos gank at lvl 2 after red.  If you see him gank top or bot at lvl 2 with red buff, you know that you'll be okay to steal his blue buff.  Basically whenever you see him gank a lane and you're on the opposite side of the map, you know that you're ok to steal his jungle.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a good shaco will steal one of your buffs usually red, because of his initial high clear speed on blue. To counter this you can do a few things, Start red or start his red, Or go right for his red after your blue. Its critical that you place at least one ward in your red side jungle. Either you or your support.

If you see shaco on your side at all immediately head for his side and farm his jungle. Shaco has the strongest counter jungle and duel potential at early levels. Your goal is to not fall too far behind. Shaco is pretty worthless late game. Thats your goal you are not going to win the early jungle.

Asking your team for help is likely to end in them leaving lane, chasing for a bit and shaco escaping.

You want to be where he isn't. Ward as much as you can, 1 ward on each side to be safe. Ping when he enters and you can at least chase him out if not get a kill on him.